# Как сделать так, чтобы при изменении TEdit'а, если TEdit пустой туда записывался '0'

Tags: delphi, edit

При изменении TEdit процедура автоматически начинает подсчёт суммы, и если очистить поле TEdit, то высвечивается ошибка " ''is not a valid integer value ", можете подсказать, что можно сделать? Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: можно при подсчете суммы проверить, пустая ли строка. и если пустая то использовать при вычислениях 0, не вписывая в сам едит ничего

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать функцию [`IntToStrDef`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_StrToIntDef.html), вместо `IntToStr`